# Fire selection event on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using a angular custom directive `range-selection` which enables the user to get the details of selected cells from a table.

Below is the working code for area selection directive for tables which has `mouseup` and `mouseup` events. i.e The `rangeChanged()` event is triggered for each cell selection. If user selects 3 cells then the event getting fired for 3 time. First time with info about one cell and second time with info about 2 cells and so on.

> **[Working demo in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-area-selection-with-directive?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html)**

I want the event to be fired only when user completes the selection. i.e If user is selecting 3 cells event should be fired after user selects 3 cells and leaves the mouse control.

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  NgZone,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent, pipe, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { filter, map, switchMap, takeUntil, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Directive({
  selector: "table[range-selection]"
})
export class RangeSelectionDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @Input() selectionClass = "state--selected";

  @Output() rangeChanged = new EventEmitter();

  selectedRange = new Set<HTMLTableCellElement>();

  private readonly table: HTMLTableElement;

  private startCell: HTMLTableCellElement = null;

  private cellIndices = new Map<
    HTMLTableCellElement,
    { row: number; column: number }
  >();

  private selecting: boolean;

  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
    { nativeElement }: ElementRef<HTMLTableElement>
  ) {
    this.table = nativeElement;
  }

  emitChanges() {
    const cells = Array.from(this.selectedRange).map(cell => {
      const rowId = (cell.parentNode as Element).id;

      return {
        cell,
        rowId
      };
    });

    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.rangeChanged.emit(cells);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.initListeners());
  }

  private initListeners() {
    const withCell = pipe(
      map((event: MouseEvent) => ({
        event,
        cell: (event.target as HTMLElement).closest<HTMLTableCellElement>(
          "mat-header-cell,td"
        )
      })),
      filter(({ cell }) => !!cell)
    );
    const mouseDown$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.table, "mousedown").pipe(
      filter(event => event.button === 0),
      withCell,
      tap(this.startSelection)
    );
    const mouseOver$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.table, "mouseover");
    const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(document, "mouseup").pipe(
      tap(() => (this.selecting = false))
    );
    this.handleOutsideClick();

    mouseDown$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => mouseOver$.pipe(takeUntil(mouseUp$))),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        withCell
      )
      .subscribe(this.select);
  }

  private handleOutsideClick() {
    fromEvent(document, "mouseup")
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((event: any) => {
        if (
          !this.selecting &&
          !this.table.contains(event.target as HTMLElement)
        ) {
          this.clearCells();
          this.emitChanges();
        }
      });
  }

  private startSelection = ({
    cell,
    event
  }: {
    event: MouseEvent;
    cell: HTMLTableCellElement;
  }) => {
    this.updateCellIndices();
    if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {
      this.clearCells();
    }

    if (event.shiftKey) {
      this.select({ cell });
    }

    this.selecting = true;
    this.startCell = cell;

    if (!event.shiftKey) {
      if (this.selectedRange.has(cell)) {
        this.selectedRange.delete(cell);
      } else {
        this.selectedRange.add(cell);
      }
      this.emitChanges();
      cell.classList.toggle(this.selectionClass);
    }
  };

  private select = ({ cell }: { cell: HTMLTableCellElement }) => {
    this.clearCells();
    this.getCellsBetween(this.startCell, cell).forEach(item => {
      this.selectedRange.add(item);
      item.classList.add(this.selectionClass);
    });
    this.emitChanges();
  };

  private clearCells() {
    Array.from(this.selectedRange).forEach(cell => {
      cell.classList.remove(this.selectionClass);
    });
    this.selectedRange.clear();
  }

  private getCellsBetween(
    start: HTMLTableCellElement,
    end: HTMLTableCellElement
  ) {
    const startCoords = this.cellIndices.get(start);
    const endCoords = this.cellIndices.get(end);
    const boundaries = {
      top: Math.min(startCoords.row, endCoords.row),
      right: Math.max(
        startCoords.column + start.colSpan - 1,
        endCoords.column + end.colSpan - 1
      ),
      bottom: Math.max(
        startCoords.row + start.rowSpan - 1,
        endCoords.row + end.rowSpan - 1
      ),
      left: Math.min(startCoords.column, endCoords.column)
    };

    const cells = [];

    iterateCells(this.table, cell => {
      const { column, row } = this.cellIndices.get(cell);
      if (
        column >= boundaries.left &&
        column <= boundaries.right &&
        row >= boundaries.top &&
        row <= boundaries.bottom
      ) {
        cells.push(cell);
      }
    });
    return cells;
  }

  private updateCellIndices() {
    this.cellIndices.clear();
    const matrix = [];
    iterateCells(this.table, (cell, y, x) => {
      for (; matrix[y] && matrix[y][x]; x++) {}
      for (let spanX = x; spanX < x + cell.colSpan; spanX++) {
        for (let spanY = y; spanY < y + cell.rowSpan; spanY++) {
          (matrix[spanY] = matrix[spanY] || [])[spanX] = 1;
        }
      }
      this.cellIndices.set(cell, { row: y, column: x });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }
}

function iterateCells(
  table: HTMLTableElement,
  callback: (cell: HTMLTableCellElement, y: number, x: number) => void
): void {
  for (let y = 0; y < table.rows.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < table.rows[y].cells.length; x++) {
      callback(table.rows[y].cells[x], y, x);
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if is there any way I can achieve this. If not in directive is there any way I can tackle this in component file only? Any help/suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Did you try with `onmouseleave()`?

Comment: @Rohith Actually I am looking to fire an event when user leaves the mouse click. He needs to hold the mouse click and hover on cells to select